# flask graphene Upload Multiple files correct way

Tags: flask, graphene-python

i try to upload multiple files using Upload Mutation with it does't work and it is very strange.

Here is my Mutation (it's accept only single file and it is work fine) but i need make to accept multiple files.  How it can be done?

```
class UploadMutation(graphene.Mutation):
    class Arguments:
        file = Upload(required=True)

    success = graphene.Boolean()

    def mutate(self, info, file, **kwargs):
        f = open('/home/dmitriy/flask/{}'.format(file.filename), 'wb')
        f.write(file.read())
        f.close()
        return UploadMutation(success=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found it's already can accept multiple files. Below is example how to use it in flask

```
class UploadMutation(graphene.Mutation):
   class Arguments:
       file = Upload(required=True)
       name = graphene.String()

   success = graphene.Boolean()
   name = graphene.String()

   def mutate(self, info, name, **kwargs):
       files = request.files

       for k,v in files.items():
           f = request.files[k]
           f.save(os.path.join('/youpath', f.filename))
           print(k,v, name)

       # do something with your file


       return UploadMutation(success=True, name=files)
```